# Not working properly Tailwind CSS warning with class webkit-appearance and vertical-align

Tags: tailwind-css

I try to use Tailwind CSS, I've just installed the tailwindcss as a  CLI installation:

[image]

[image]

It's not working properly, they send some warning with class `-webkit-appearance` and `vertical-align`.

How can I resolve this problem and what caused this error?

<> I can't find any solution with it help me to solve this </>

I set as CSS>Line Unknown At Rules but problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are pretty straightforward.

`-webkit-appearance` is [a CSS extension for browsers with the webkit engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions). You should also add `appearance` for compatibility with other browsers.

`vertical-align` has no effect when used in an element with `display: block`. `display: block` is the default for any HTML element, unless you change it. So if you want `vertical-align` you need to set `display` to [something else](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php).

Comment: But as soon as I installed. there has no sign to ready for work .